# Operating system software task scheduling

Tags: assembly, process, operating-system

I was wondering how does the scheduler get control back from the loaded assembly code? For example we could write a program body to which control is passed from the scheduler.

```
;Do whatever we need to do before calling main()
;Call main or jump to it
;Do cleanup and stuff
```

So how one can return the program flow from the main back to the scheduler?
I have been thinking that process loader could inject `jmp` instructions to return the program flow back to the scheduler. Any idea could that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[short version]

OS loaders do not insert any jmp or call code.

On modern preemptive OS, the kernel code is entered from interrupts, either:

'Real' hardware interrupts from peripherals like disk, NIC, KB, mouse, timer that cause a driver to run.

Software interrupts, ie. system calls.

Either type of interrupt may request a scheduler run and change the set of threads running on cores.

If there are no interrupts, the kernel does nothing because it is not entered.

Answer (score 2):

The scheduler doesnt inject jumps or something like that. The os registered it to a interrupt service routine. (isr) of a timerinterrupt of your cpu.

Comment: What about all the other interrupts from I/O peripherals?

Comment: This is implementation dependend, some isr's start a specific driver, some feed a buffer, ... Many ways are possible. You have to look up your operating systems documentation to get a specific info.

Answer (score 2):

Multitasking is either implemented preemptive, oder kooperative.

Most OSes uses a preemptive strategy, which mneans that the OS assigns a certain amount of time to a thread, which it is allowed to run. When the timer expires, an interrupt is generated and the OS forcibly switches to a new task (if there are some). This can not really be prevented from user space, unless there are mecahnisms provided.

In a kooperative environment, the process runs as long as it needs to. It explicitly has to call a function which allows the OS to switch to a new task. As long as the process doesn't do this, it can theoretically run forever.

In both cases, it can happen that the task executes a systemcall, which requires the task to wait, and in such a case a task switch can also happen, until the waiting resource call is satsified.

Comment: On preemptive systems, the kernel does nothing unless it is entered from a system call or a hardware interrupt via a driver. The timer interrupt, (on most systems/OS), is just one of many and highlighting it explicitly, or by implication, gives a poor impression of how most such systems operate.

Comment: @MartinJames, thanks for the explanation. I think that this is an implementation detail though, so the general concept still applies.

Comment: The only mainstream cooperative multitasking systems were Windows 3.x and MacOS before MacOS X. Both are rather outdated.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, There are other OSes as well, not neccessarily mainstream. In fact I was working on something like this, for a company with their own hardware.

Answer (score 1):

OS is interrupted by the timer and if program time is elapsed it calls scheduler that choose next program to execute until next interrupt.
If you ask about "how OS know that the program execution is finished" - Program's process make system call when it finish and OS mark that process dead and so scheduler won't choose it for execution.

Comment: Timer.. and all the other vitally important I/O interrupts.